# Netflix Player addEventListener for timeupdate

Tags: javascript, netflix

I want to listen netflix player for every time is updated. Here my code:

```
const videoPlayer = netflix.appContext.state.playerApp.getAPI().videoPlayer;
const player = videoPlayer.getVideoPlayerBySessionId(videoPlayer.getAllPlayerSessionIds()[0]);
```

Above code is working. Problem is:

```
player.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(e){
    console.log("time updated");
    // Other code will be here ...
});
```

I tried this but "time updated" never write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a tricky one. Because Netflix API doesn't use the "timeupdate" event for the event listener, so, you can look into your player object and search for "cia" Map object and you`ll get all the event listener API you need.

### Solution

The event you are looking for is "**currenttimechanged**":

[image]

The code should be like:

```
const videoPlayer = netflix.appContext.state.playerApp.getAPI().videoPlayer;
const player = videoPlayer.getVideoPlayerBySessionId(videoPlayer.getAllPlayerSessionIds()[0]);

player.addEventListener("currenttimechanged", () => console.log(player.getCurrentTime()));
```